# Is this a bug in Django or what? Logging out of the Django Authentication system...will remove all sessiosn?

Tags: python, django, session

I'm using sessions across my application.
And using logins.

When I do a simple:

```
#log out the user.
logout(request)
```

...the request.sessions get erased.

What is this??!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by `request.sessions` you mean `request.session`, then it's a documented feature:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.logout

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct syntax is:

```
logout(request.user)
```

Comment: If the OP didn't seem so distressed by the deletion of all his sessions, I would find this mildly amusing.

Comment: No, Django documentation says `logout(request)`.